# Asp.Net Mvc Loading Progress

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, counter

We have 4 Batchfiles which read Content from a Server. These 4 Batchfiles are numbered. The Batchfiles are executed one after the other and after each execute we want to increase a counter from 1 to 4. We want to display this in the Html with Javascript. Is there any Option to do this?
This is our do while loop where we want to setup the counter (its in a ActionResult called Execute):

```
            do
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                procList = Process.GetProcessesByName("Serverfiles").ToList();
                //procList = Process.GetProcesses().ToList();
                int counter = procList.Count; //our counter
                ViewBag.counter = counter; //our try with a viewbag
                
                
            }
            while (procList.Count > 0);
```

Comment: You can achieve this with singalR

Comment: Could you make an example? Or explain it a bit? That would be really nice and thank you for your answer!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-high-frequency-realtime-with-signalr

Comment: But our exact Problem is that we have a 'document.GetElementbyId().innerHtml = @Viewbag.Counter' the Viewbag refreshes but the Html doesnt

Comment: Viewbag is returned at when the action result is returned, meaning that that only the last iteration will be returned once completed, You will need to change that logic to send the update via SignalR for example so that this now updates the UI instead